Get the number of queries whose execution time is more than 3 seconds
I have a specific endpoint and for it, I need to form the correct request to get all requests for the last 5 minutes that have an execution time of more than 3 seconds and check that their number is more than 10
I used the following query, but it doesn't work correctly
count_over_time(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{env=~"myEnv", group="myGroup", uri="myUri", le="3"}[5m]) > 10

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

I wonder if it has something like the SlowQuery.log that is built into Mysql ?

Instead of count_over_time it should be increase.
